# How to restrict CloudFront and S3 access the best way

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, mobile, amazon-cloudfront

I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the correct place for this type of questions, however I want to try it. If it is not fine, please close this question.

so, here is my scenario:

I'm building up a mobile app for Android and iOS with a large CDN-backend for my file content that the app is supposed to be using.
Right now, I fired up a S3-bucket and denied all public access whatsoever. Also I brought a cloudfront distribution that can access this bucket in order to use edge and restrict my content to certain countries.
However, I only need read-access for the app that is going to be deployed.

Now here is my question:

- Is it best practice to bring up some kind of access token in order to ensure only the app can read-access the content? This token could be coded into the app and all traffic from outside this app would be prohibited

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This can maybe help:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think signed url can help in same. Please refer to below document from AWS.

CloudFront uses the public key to validate the signature and confirm that the URL hasn't been tampered with. If the signature is invalid, the request is rejected.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html